# How to replace css using jquery after user agent detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this code to detect android native browser:

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));
```

but how can I create function to repleace css after detection?

I know I should use something like that:

```
$('jQuery selector').css({"css property name":"css property value"});
```

but I don't now how :(

On the same page is other function that is using jquery.

Comment: Change css of which element?

Comment: @p0mian check this link http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Don't set/reset CSS properties, instead add/remove classes.

Comment: I can't think a case where you want to change 1 or 2 elements based on a specific browser. Perhaps you want to change to another CSS file, containing all the changes for Android devices?

Comment: If it is just for detecting android, can't we have it like this `if(nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));

if (is_android){
  //for eg you want to remove border of a div with id #container
  $('#container').css({"border":"none"});
  //Best is to have a class created in css with which ever property you want to remove
  // if the class was .green-color
  $('#container').removeClass('green-color');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both Url as following that hopefully can help you to deal with your problems

[How can I use JQuery to replace CSS background image and maintain gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649735/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-replace-css-background-image-and-maintain-gradient)

[Replace CSS property with jQuery conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558228/replace-css-property-with-jquery-conditional)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add a classname to `<html>` or `<body>` tag, with that trick you can modify the pure CSS without jquery selectors and DOM manipulation, making it really flexible and performance:

```
 if(is_android) { 
       $('html').addClass('android');
 } else {
       $('html').removeClass('android');
 }
```

and then with CSS as simple as this:

```
 h1 { color:blue; }
 .android h1 { color:green; }
 .android body {background: black; }
```